# Wrap async await queries in try catch

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I originally had `try...catch` in my getAllUsers method for querying but ended up removing it because as far as I could tell it wasn't doing anything. I know the async function returns a promise so it should be fine and actually based on how the code is structured I think it's required otherwise the `try...catch` in the query would swallow the error. Is there anything I'm missing with this structure and use of `async/await`, `try...catch`, and `.then .catch`?

```
let getAllUsers = async () => {
  let res = await models.users.findAll({
      attributes: [ 'firstName', 'lastName' ]
    });
    return res;
};

router.get(`${path}`, (req, res) => {
    queries.users.getAllUsers()
      .then(users => {
        res.status(200).json(users);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error)
      });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's just no reason to use `await` at all in your function.  Instead of this:

```
let getAllUsers = async () => {
    let res = await models.users.findAll({
      attributes: [ 'firstName', 'lastName' ]
    });
    return res;
};
```

It can just be this:

```
let getAllUsers = () => {
    return models.users.findAll({
      attributes: [ 'firstName', 'lastName' ]
    });
};
```

You just return the promise directly and the caller uses the promise the same as you already were.  Since you are not using the result within your `getAllUsers()` function or coordinating it with anything else, there's no reason to use `await`.  And, since there's no use of `await`, there's no reason for the function to be declared `async` either.

---

If you wanted to use `await`, you could use it for the caller of `getAllUsers()` like this:

```
router.get(`${path}`, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let users = await queries.users.getAllUsers();
        res.status(200).json(users);
    } catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
});
```

And, here you would have to use try/catch in order to catch rejected promises.  Personally, I don't see how this is particularly better than what you had originally with `.then()` and `.catch()` so for a situation as simple as this (with no coordination or serialization with other promises), it's really just a matter of personal preference whether to use `.then()` and `.catch()` or `await` with `try/catch`.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `async/await` with the code that calls `getAllUsers` rather than using it in `getAllUsers` itself:

```
const getAllUsers = () => {
  return models.users.findAll({
      attributes: [ 'firstName', 'lastName' ]
    });
};

router.get(`${path}`, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await queries.users.getAllUsers();
        res.status(200).json(users);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to handle this is using middleware.

Here is the function:

```
// based upon this
// http://madole.xyz/error-handling-in-express-with-async-await-routes/
// https://github.com/madole/async-error-catcher

export default function asyncErrorCatcher(fn) {
    if (!(fn instanceof Function)) {
        throw new Error("Must supply a function");
    }

    return (request, response, next) => {
        const promise = fn(request, response, next);
        if (!promise.catch) {
             return;
        }
        promise.catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
            response.sendStatus(500);
        });

    };
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
router.get("/getSettings/", asyncErrorCatcher(async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
  const settings = await database.getSettings();
  response.json(settings);
}));
```

Comment: How does `const promise = fn(request, response, next);` work, it doesn't seem that the function you passed in always return a promise, it doesn't return anything.